# Hive Table is Empty check

Tags: java, hive

How can I check if a particular table say table A is empty in hive.I need to store this as boolean value to a variable in my java code.I tried this

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.execute("Select count(*) from "+tableName);
    int ct = stmt.getUpdateCount();
    logger.info("Hive Table count is " +ct);
    if(ct > 0)
      return false;
    else
     return true;
```

but this doesnot seem to work. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select count(*) from "+tableName);
    int ct = rs.getInt(0);
    logger.info("Hive Table count is " +ct);
    if(ct > 0)
      return false;
    else
     return true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it this way :

```
ResultSet resultSet;
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from "+tableName);
int count = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    count++;
} 
if(count == 0) // Table is empty.
```

Comment: This solution has complexity proportional to number of rows in table while OP's solution is O(1).